# Use mingw-get to install du

Tags: mingw, du

Does anyone know how to use `mingw-get install` to install the unix `du` command?

I couldn't find which package to use.  `mingw-get install du` does not work.

This is with 32 bit MinGW/MSYS from [mingw.org](http://www.mingw.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mingw-get` works with packages rather than individual binaries, as does `apt-get`. The `du` binary is part of the `coreutils` package, so try

```
mingw-get install coreutils
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried `mingw-get install msys-coreutils`, and it works.